# HTTP headers на WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, header, индексация

Как настроить правильную индексацию сайта на WordPress с помощью `X-Robots-Tag`!
Я собираюсь прописать http заголовок для того, что бы почистить индекс, но совершенно не шарю php(. Подскажите, куда и как прописывать http заголовок `X-Robots-Tag` в WordPress?
Я имеюю ввиду, в какой файл, в каком месте и (очень желательно) как учесть то, что он (заголовок) должен отдаватся не всем, а по регулярному выражению.
Буду признателен за любой совет!

Comment: Чем вас robots.txt не устраивает?

Comment: Роботс хорош, когда в индексе нет мусора. А вот что бы почистить, то, что туда уже влетело рекомендуют использовать X-Robots-Tag

Comment: Вот пример внедрения X-Robots-Tag через .htaccess https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag?hl=ru#---x-robots-tag--apache

Comment: Увы, но это рекомендация для серверов Apache, а у меня nginix

Comment: Вот http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29691504/how-to-prevent-xml-files-from-indexing-by-google-on-rails-with-nginx-setup#29691534 пример правила для Nginx, чтобы не индексировал определенные типы файлов. По аналогии можно составить правила на основе регулярок более сложных, если надо.